# Как сделать внешний отступ внутренним?

Tags: html, css, padding

Что я имею в виду? Я хочу сделать один блок, в который я помещу все содержимое сайта. Этому блоку я задам правый и левый padding'и в 20рх. Таким образом при сжатии все содержимое сайта не будет прилипать к границам окна браузера.

Все бы хорошо, но не совсем выходит. На странице у меня есть фото на всю ширину окна браузера. При добавлении padding'ов с двух сторон, блок с фото уже не на всю ширину.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтоб отступ включал в себя размер всех блоков и был внутренним (надеюсь понятно)? Не сильно хочется каждому блоку на странице писать `padding: 0 20px`.

Comment: можно увеличить фото через `transform: scale()`.

Comment: @DiD можно, но там еще помимо фото есть и другие блоки, которые на весь экран должны идти. Наверное самое лучшее и безопасное решение это все-таки padding каждому эл-ту (можно через общий класс)

Comment: Если нужно отступать только inline-элементам, можно сделать два невидимых блока `float: left` и `float: right`. Тогда можно обойтимь без padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, так не надо делать, пожалуйста не портите верстку и не изобретайте мопед.

Все на много проще и легче делается.

Вам необходимо научится не бояться важных классов, вроде как "wrapper". Алгоритм следующий:

Вы создаете секцию, только внутри нее *ВНУТРИ СЕЦИИ, А НЕ НА УРОВНЕ СЕКЦИИ задаете  padding/margin , блок поверх  wrapper  может оставаться как для фона, так и для фоновой картинке. Самой фоновой картинке необходимо задать стили, которые помогут нормально встать ей на всю ширину/высоту экрана.

Я предоставлю код в  html  для более простого понимания:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="header">
        <div class="header__body">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h2 class="header__title title">header</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="nav">
        <div class="nav__body">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h2 class="nav__title title">nav</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="footer">
        <div class="footer__body">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <h2 class="footer__title title">footer</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

PS - Можно пойти через absolute, но тогда  relative  должен быть в не зоне padding, но стоит ли оно того, не скажу. Снова велосипед какой-то, который для обычных задач не нужен.

Comment: Ага, понятно. Похожее решение - добавление padding'ов к секции, а не к самому wrapper'у (результат получается точно такой же). Я так делала

Comment: Такова быть не может, если только вы не сбросили стандартные отступы браузера в  body. И НЕ  нужно добавлять padding/margin  секции. Это указывается блокам ниже, т.е ребенку.

Comment: да, все отступы были обнулены